# Can you export multiple classes from a single Nodejs Module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

Currently, I have 4 Child Classes each in their own file. I'm requiring them all in the same file. I am wondering if I can contain all 4 of those classes in a single module. Currently, I'm importing them like this

```
var Jack = require('./Jack.js');
var JackInstance = new Jack();
var Jones = require('./Jones.js');
var JonesInstance = new Jones();
```

I'd like to import them like this

```
var People = require('./People.js');
var JackInstance = new People.Jack();
```

Or even

```
var Jack = require('./People.js').Jack;
var JackInstance = new Jack();
```

My classes are defined like so

```
class Jack{
    //Memeber variables, functions, etc
}

module.exports = Jack;
```

Answer (score 118, accepted):

You can export multiple classes like this:

e.g. **People.js**

```
class Jack{
   //Member variables, functions, etc
}

class John{
   //Member variables, functions, etc
}

module.exports = {
  Jack : Jack,
  John : John
}
```

And access these classes as you have correctly mentioned:

```
var People = require('./People.js');
var JackInstance = new People.Jack();
var JohnInstance = new People.John();
```

Comment: REALLY!? I tried this exact method earlier! Let me try again. I'll accept your ans asap.

Comment: As it turns out, I just had a typo. Thanks!!

Comment: @MukeshSharma: I want class Jack and John will be in a separate file like jack.js and john.js...then will require people.js and want to access jack instance using people.jack. could you please help?

Comment: would destructuring work? `var {John, Jack} = require('./People.js'); var JackInstance = new Jack();`

Answer (score 85):

You can also do this in a shorter form, using [destructuring assignments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) (which are supported natively starting from Node.js [v6.0.0](http://node.green/#ES2015-syntax-destructuring--declarations-with-objects)):

```
// people.js

class Jack {
  // ...
}

class John {
  // ...
}

module.exports = { Jack, John }
```

Importing:

```
// index.js

const { Jack, John } = require('./people.js');
```

Or even like this if you want aliased require assignments:

```
// index.js

const {
  Jack: personJack, John: personJohn,
} = require('./people.js');
```

In the latter case `personJack` and `personJohn` will reference your classes.

**A word of warning:**

Destructuring could be dangerous in sense that it's prone to producing unexpected errors. It's relatively easy to forget curly brackets on `export` or to accidentally include them on `require`.

---

**Node.js 12 update:**

Lately ECMAScript Modules received an extended support in [Node.js 12.*](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html), introducing the convenient usage of `import` statement to accomplish the same task (currently Node should be started with a flag `--experimental-modules` in order to make them available).

```
// people.mjs

export class Jack {
  // ...
}

export class John {
  // ...
}
```

Notice that files that adhere to modules convention should have an `.mjs` extension.

```
// index.mjs

import {
  Jack as personJack, John as personJohn,
} from './people.mjs';
```

This is much better in a sense of robustness and stability, as an attempt to `import` non-existing `export` from the module will throw an exception similar to:

> SyntaxError: The requested module 'x' does not provide an export named
>   'y'