# ReferenceError: Object is not defined when I define multilplie classes at same file

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, class-transformer

I use node.js 7.44.

In file user.models.ts I have multilplie classes like:

```
import { Exclude, Expose } from "class-transformer";

export class User {
    @Expose() _id: string;
    @Expose() fname: string;
    @Expose() lname: string;
    @Expose() birthday: Date;   
    @Expose() address: Address;

    constructor(){...}
}

@Exclude()
export class Address {
    @Expose() street: string;
    @Expose() num: number;
    @Expose() city: string;
    @Expose() zipCode: number;
}
```

When I compile the server I get the error `ReferenceError: Adress is not defined`

How can I use multilplie classes at same file?

Comment: First define the class and then use it. Because concept of hoisting is not applicable on the classes.

Comment: note: i think you are supposed to export juste one object per file, see the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41228221/can-you-export-multiple-classes-from-a-single-nodejs-module

Comment: **Shubham** thx it really work!

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using `Address` in `User`, you have to define `Address` first. Consider using the eslint rule [no-use-before-define](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-use-before-define).

```
import { Exclude, Expose } from "class-transformer";

@Exclude()
export class Address {
    @Expose() street: string;
    @Expose() num: number;
    @Expose() city: string;
    @Expose() zipCode: number;
}

export class User {
    @Expose() _id: string;
    @Expose() fname: string;
    @Expose() lname: string;
    @Expose() birthday: Date;   
    @Expose() address: Address;

    constructor(){...}
}
```