# Function give undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, class, callback

I am working on login process using `nodejs`, and I want to define a global function outside of module then call it multiple time in the module but it always return undefined, while when I console.log into it, I found that there is data.
first, this is an example of facebook login strategy that I use :

```
  class Auth {  
      FacebookStrategy(req, res) {
                passport.use('facebook', new Facebook({
                    clientID: process.env.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID,
                    clientSecret: process.env.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET,
                    callbackURL: `http://${process.env.DOMAINE}/auth/facebook/callback`,
                    profileFields: ["email", "name", "photos", "displayName"],
                    passReqToCallback: true
                }, (req, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
                    let db = req.app.db;
                    db.collection("utilisateur").findOne({ "email": profile.emails[0].value, "isdelete": { $exists: false } },
                        async function (err, user) {
                            if (err) done({ "mongo err ": err })
                            if (user) {
                                let newJWT = await generateJWT(user);
                                 let tokenUpdate = await updateDBJWT(req.app.db, user._id, newJWT);
                                // return db.collection("utilisateur").findOneAndUpdate({ "_id": user._id }, { $set: { "token": newJWT } },
                                //     { returnOriginal: false }, (err, user) => {
                                //         if (err) return (err)
                                //         done(null, user.value);
                                //     });
                                done(user,tokenUpdate);
                            } else {
                                let newUser = {};
                                newUser.name = profile.displayName;
                                newUser.email = profile.emails[0].value;
                                newUser.role = 'client';
                                newUser.image = profile.photos[0].value;
                                newUser.dateInsert = moment().utc(1).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
                                newUser.connextionProvider = {
                                    "provider_id": profile.id,
                                    "provider": 'facebook'
                                };
                                let token = generateJWT(newUser);
                                newUser.token = token;
                                db.collection("utilisateur").insertOne(newUser, async function (err, insertedUser) {
                                    if (err) done(err);
                                    let data = insertedUser.ops[0];
                                    done(null, data);
                                });
                            }
                        });
                })
                );
            }
}
module.exports = Auth;
```

and my problem is with this field tokenUpload, it always back undefined

```
let tokenUpdate = await updateDBJWT(req.app.db, user._id, newJWT);
```

and here is the updateDBJWT in the same page with auth class but outside the module

```
function updateDBJWT(db, userId, token) {
    return db.collection("utilisateur").findOneAndUpdate({ "_id": userId }, { $set: { "token": token } }, { returnOriginal: false }, (err, user) => {
        if (err) return (err)
        console.log('user value ', user.value);
        return (user.value);
    });
}
```

every time i replace the tokenUpload line with the function, it work without problem but when i call it it give nothing, i ll be grateful if any one help, thank you

Comment: True, @ScottSauyet... But that does not make it `undefined`. My guess is the `module.exports` only exports the class... So the `updateDBJWT` function does not follow. Not sure... But I would look for this. Either you put the function in the class... Or you also export the function.

Comment: Look here: [Can you export multiple classes from a single Nodejs Module?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41228318/2159528).... It looks relevant. ;)

Comment: @Louys it worked very well, first time but then it didnt' work, and i don't want to export it, i just want to call it, if you have any idea if i make it in the same module how i can call it then tell me

Comment: i resolved the problem with calling the function, now the problem how to get the value from updateDBJWT function, because it seems that i am returning the data in the wrong wat

Comment: Can't be sure of anything here... but why `return (user.value);`? Why not simply `return (user);` ? That is a database output... not an HTML input. ;)

Comment: it's the same but here the problem is nodejs skip the line return db.collection... and i don't know why - @Louys

Comment: mmm... On line #12 of a copy/paste of your code, `async function (err, user) {`... `async` seems useless there, unless you call something else that is async. I did not fully dived in your code, ;) But you provide a callback function to execute once a record is found. And that executes immediately. -- I doubt it can be the issue... but just test a removal of it if you are unsure. --- Inside `generateJWT` function. If you add add `console.log("HERE")`, does it show?

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette yes it show even when i do console.log(user) inside it, it show it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Its due the async behaviour of "findOneAndUpdate() function",
>   findAndUpdate takes time to execute update query and interpreter not
>   wait for the result and return undefined in the response.

I know you are using async/await but that not worked in required manner.

> So what you can do is wrap your updateDBJWT() function into a promise
>   function and resolve when the result is comes else reject.
>
> And wrap the whole code into a then function, from where you are
>   calling updateDBJWT() function.

**I have made the changes below, you just need to copy paste and check it worked or not**

Do something like this:-

```
function updateDBJWT(db, userId, token) {
return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
    db.collection("utilisateur").findOneAndUpdate({ "_id": userId }, { $set: { "token": token } }, { returnOriginal: false }, (err, user) => {
        if (err) reject (err)
     else{
        console.log('user value ', user.value);
        resolve (user.value);
     }

    });
})

}
```

In your main code:-

```
   class Auth {  
      FacebookStrategy(req, res) {
                passport.use('facebook', new Facebook({
                    clientID: process.env.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID,
                    clientSecret: process.env.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET,
                    callbackURL: `http://${process.env.DOMAINE}/auth/facebook/callback`,
                    profileFields: ["email", "name", "photos", "displayName"],
                    passReqToCallback: true
                }, (req, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
                    let db = req.app.db;
                    db.collection("utilisateur").findOne({ "email": profile.emails[0].value, "isdelete": { $exists: false } },
                        async function (err, user) {
                            if (err) done({ "mongo err ": err })
                            if (user) {
                                let newJWT = await generateJWT(user);
                                  updateDBJWT(req.app.db, user._id, newJWT).then(function(tokenUpdate){
                                    done(user,tokenUpdate);
                                  }).catch(function(err){
                                      console.error(err);
                                  })
                                // return db.collection("utilisateur").findOneAndUpdate({ "_id": user._id }, { $set: { "token": newJWT } },
                                //     { returnOriginal: false }, (err, user) => {
                                //         if (err) return (err)
                                //         done(null, user.value);
                                //     });

                            } else {
                                let newUser = {};
                                newUser.name = profile.displayName;
                                newUser.email = profile.emails[0].value;
                                newUser.role = 'client';
                                newUser.image = profile.photos[0].value;
                                newUser.dateInsert = moment().utc(1).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
                                newUser.connextionProvider = {
                                    "provider_id": profile.id,
                                    "provider": 'facebook'
                                };
                                let token = generateJWT(newUser);
                                newUser.token = token;
                                db.collection("utilisateur").insertOne(newUser, async function (err, insertedUser) {
                                    if (err) done(err);
                                    let data = insertedUser.ops[0];
                                    done(null, data);
                                });
                            }
                        });
                })
                );
            }
}
module.exports = Auth;
```

If still you are getting undefined, let me know.

Hope it will help!

Comment: Yep, that solver my problem, thank you very muchhhhhh